# Android 5.0 makes unselected checkboxes invisible when background is white

Tags: android, checkbox, xamarin, android-5.0-lollipop

I have an android app that has been working fine pre-Android 5.0. With the update, I noticed that checkboxes and radiobuttons placed on white backgrounds are not visible if they are not selected. For example, this is what a checkbox looks selected and unselected in jellybean:

[image]   [image]

As you can see, there is a light gray square when the checkbox is not selected. However, after updating to lollipop, this is what it looks like:

[image][image]

So, as you can see, there is no gray square or anything that suggests there is a checkbox here. The same problem happens with radiobuttons. I really don't want to go trough the pain of creating new drawables just for this simple ting. I have seen that checkboxes within the accessibility menu of android 5 have a nice square, but haven't figured out how to make mine look the same:

[image]

I tried creating a new android project and just adding some checkboxes and radio buttons with a white background, but they are still invisible when unchecked. I'm using xamarin studio and c#, if that makes any difference. Anyway, I'll understand any java code you post.

This is what my checkbox code looks like:

```
          <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/chkSeleccionar"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:scaleX="1.5"
            android:scaleY="1.3"
            android:layout_weight="50"
          />
```

Comment: What theme are you using?

Comment: I think it is Holo. I have defined some styles, but just for the action bar and dialogs. How can I be sure it is holo?

Comment: Look for an `android:theme` element in your AndroidManifest.xml file (either on your application or on an individual activity), then look up what style is set there and check the `parent` attribute for the style.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it is Holo.

Comment: Hey, thank you. You helped me spot the problem. I changed my app's theme to Material.Light and now they all look good.

Comment: @AlexTerreaux : Did changing to Material.Light theme affect the previous android versions?

Comment: @Ashwin No, because I defined the style for Lollipop only,  leaving the themes for other versions of android unaffected.

Comment: same problem, but just CheckBox disappears when selected. And selected answer should be different. It's not logical to change theme of entire activity or project for one CheckBox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are using a Material theme for Android 5.0 devices - this will ensure you're styling remains consistent with other components. Look for an `android:theme` element in your AndroidManifest.xml file (either on your application or on an individual activity), then look up what style is set there and check the `parent` attribute for the style.

Answer (score 11):

I couldn't get the theme working, but what did work for me was the following:

```
android:button="@drawable/abc_btn_check_material"
android:buttonTint="@color/red"
```

Put this into your CheckBox XML layout.

Comment: plus 1 for android:buttonTint

Comment: android:button="@drawable/abc_btn_check_material" gives warning as private

Answer (score 9):

Just change the

```
android:buttonTint="YOUR COLOR"
```

It works.

Answer (score 2):

Add this attribute

```
android:buttonTint="#EEEEEE"
```